# Marking anomalies in 1D data

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-science

I have a few lists of movement tracking data, which looks something like this

[image]

I want to create a list of outputs where I mark these large spikes, essentially telling that there is a movement at that point.

I applied a rolling standard deviation on the data with a window size of two and got this result [image]

Now I can see the spikes which mark the point of interest, but I am not sure how to do it in code. A statistical tool to measure these spikes, which can be used to flag these spikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches that you can use for an anomaly detection task. 
The choice depends on your data.

If you want to use a statistical approach, you can use some measures like z-score or IQR.
[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/statistical-techniques-for-anomaly-detection-6ac89e32d17a) you can find a tutorial for these measures.

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-anomaly-detection-algorithm-from-scratch-in-python-step-by-step-guide-e1daf870336e) instead, you can find another tutorial for a statistical approach which uses mean and variance.

Last but not least, I suggest you also to check how to use a [control chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart), because in some cases it's enough.